# EF6 reverse engineer code first does not generate correct column names when same table is used by multiple foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework Power Tools beta 4 with VS 2013 and the totally fantastic Reverse Engineer Code First feature.

One of my tables is defined as follows (I've stripped out some of the other columns and details):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MentoringProfile](
[ProfileID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MCGExperienceID] [int] NULL,
[IndustryExperienceID] [int] NULL,
[PrefMCGExperienceID] [int] NULL,
[PrefIndustryExperienceID] [int] NULL,
```

All of the columns that contain the word Experience have a FK relationship with the Experience table which, predictably, looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Experience](
[ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ExperienceLevel] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
```

When I generate the code I get a MentoringProfile.cs class that looks like this:

```
public partial class MentoringProfile
{
    public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MCGExperienceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IndustryExperienceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PrefMCGExperienceID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PrefIndustryExperienceID { get; set; }
    public virtual Experience Experience { get; set; }
    public virtual Experience Experience1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Experience Experience2 { get; set; }
    public virtual Experience Experience3 { get; set; }
}
```

and MentoringProfileMap.cs contains this:

```
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Experience)
            .WithMany(t => t.MentoringProfiles)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PrefMCGExperienceID);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Experience1)
            .WithMany(t => t.MentoringProfiles1)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.PrefIndustryExperienceID);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Experience2)
            .WithMany(t => t.MentoringProfiles2)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MCGExperienceID);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Experience3)
            .WithMany(t => t.MentoringProfiles3)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.IndustryExperienceID);
```

Is there any way to get RECF to generate names for the virtual columns to match the Nullable columns?  I just want Experience1 to be IndustryExperience, for example.  Trying to figure out what Experience1, 2, or 3 maps to in my code is very confusing.

Comment: Reverese engineering code first is now integrated in the new EF model dialog. Maybe you should try that first. But then, the tools are only meant to give you a one-time-only kick start into a CF model. You're totally free to rename the generated properties afterwards. The generated mapping files will show you to which db columns they are mapped.

Comment: I was hoping to have a fix that would take care of it each time I run the generator.  If I have to tweak the generated code every time I run it then it's not saving me as much time.  Today, for example, I ran it half a dozen times as I changed the db.  I think I have the latest versions of everything, but I can't seem to figure out where in VS you are referring when you say "Reverese engineering code first is now integrated in the new EF model dialog".  Hint?

Comment: If you add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model one of the options is "Code First from database". But for what you're doing I think Reverse POCO Generator is more suitable.